# Setup ox-extra in an elisp script to be run without init file

Tags: org-mode, org-export, package

I'm new to Emacs and I am trying to write an elisp script to automate the org-mode export for GitLab CI. The idea is that on the worker I simply run `emacs --batch --no-init-file --load build.el --funcall org-publish-all` to export my org project.

Since I use the `:ignore:` tag I need the `(ox-extras-activate '(ignore-headlines))` line in my `build.el`. This obviously reports `Symbol’s function definition is void: ox-extras-activate`, but with (`ox-extra` is part of `org-plus-contrib`):

```lisp
(require 'package)
(package-initialize)
(add-to-list 'package-archives '("org" . "https://orgmode.org/elpa/") t)
(add-to-list 'package-archives '("org-plus-contrib" . "https://orgmode.org/elpa/") t)
(package-refresh-contents)

(require 'org)
(require 'ox-extra)

(ox-extras-activate '(ignore-headlines))
```

I got this error: `Cannot open load file: File o directory non esistente, ox-extra`.

I tried also with

```lisp
(require 'package)
(package-initialize)
(add-to-list 'package-archives '("org" . "https://orgmode.org/elpa/") t)
(add-to-list 'package-archives '("org-plus-contrib" . "https://orgmode.org/elpa/") t)
(package-refresh-contents)

(package-install 'org)
(package-install 'ox-extra)

(require 'org)
(require 'ox-extra)

(ox-extras-activate '(ignore-headlines))
```

which causes `Package ‘ox-extra-’ is unavailable`.

So I cannot find a way to setup `ox-extra`.

Full `build.el`:

```lisp
;; build.el --- Build orgmode book

;;; Commentary:
;; This script will export the book

;;; Code:

(require 'package)
(package-initialize)
(add-to-list 'package-archives '("org" . "https://orgmode.org/elpa/") t)
(add-to-list 'package-archives '("org-plus-contrib" . "https://orgmode.org/elpa/") t)
(package-refresh-contents)

(package-install 'org)
(package-install 'ox-extra)

(require 'org)
(require 'ox-extra)

(ox-extras-activate '(ignore-headlines))

(setq ; org-export-with-section-numbers nil
      org-export-with-smart-quotes t
      ; org-export-with-toc nil
      )

;; Minted
(setq org-export-latex-listings 'minted
      org-latex-packages-alist '(("" "minted"))
      org-latex-minted-options
      '(("autogobble=true") ("breaklines=true"))
      org-latex-pdf-process
      (mapcar
       (lambda (s)
         (replace-regexp-in-string "%latex " "%latex -shell-escape " s))
       org-latex-pdf-process))
  
;; Prepare to export
(setq org-html-divs '((preamble "header" "top")
                      (content "main" "content")
                      (postamble "footer" "postamble"))
      org-html-container-element "section"
      org-html-metadata-timestamp-format "%d/%m/%Y"
      org-html-checkbox-type 'html
      org-html-html5-fancy t
      ; org-html-validation-link nil
      org-html-doctype "html5")

(defvar site-attachments
  (regexp-opt '("jpg" "jpeg" "gif" "png" "svg"
                "ico" "cur" "css" "js" "woff" "woff2" "html" 
                ; "pdf"
                ))
  "File types that are published as static files.")

(setq
 common (list
         :base-directory "."
         :base-extension "org"
         :recursive nil
         :exclude (regexp-opt '("README" "LICENSE"))
         )
 )


;; Export
(setq org-publish-project-alist
      (list
       (append '("latex-org") common (list
                                      :publishing-function '(org-latex-export-to-pdf)
                                      :publishing-directory "."
                                      ))
       (append '("html-org") common (list
                                     :publishing-function '(org-html-export-to-html)
                                     :publishing-directory "./public"
                                     ;; :auto-sitemap t
                                     ;; :sitemap-filename "index.org"
                                     ;; :sitemap-file-entry-format "%d *%t*"
                                     ;; :html-head-extra "<link rel=\"icon\" type=\"image/x-icon\" href=\"/favicon.ico\"/>"
                                     ;; :sitemap-style 'list
                                     ;; :sitemap-sort-files 'anti-chronologically
                                     ))
       (list "site-static"
             :base-directory "."
             :exclude "public/"
             :base-extension site-attachments
             :publishing-directory "./public"
             :publishing-function 'org-publish-attachment
             :recursive t)
       (list "site" :components '("html-org" "site-static"))
       ))

(add-to-list 'org-latex-classes
             '("elegantbook"
               "\\documentclass{elegantbook}"
               ("\\part{%s}" . "\\part*{%s}")
               ("\\chapter{%s}" . "\\chapter*{%s}")
               ("\\section{%s}" . "\\section*{%s}")
               ("\\subsection{%s}" . "\\subsection*{%s}")
               ("\\subsubsection{%s}" . "\\subsubsection*{%s}")))

(provide 'build)
;;; build.el ends here
```

Comment: I am not sure how this all works, but you probably have to `(package-install 'org-contrib)` (it is separate from `org`).

Comment: `Package ‘org-contrib-’ is unavailable`, but now that you tell me I tried also with `(package-install 'org-plus-contrib)` and finally it works!
Thank you very much

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by @dalanicolai the solution was simply to install `org-plus-contrib` instead of `ox-extra`:

```lisp
(require 'package)
(package-initialize)
(add-to-list 'package-archives '("org" . "https://orgmode.org/elpa/") t)
(add-to-list 'package-archives '("org-plus-contrib" . "https://orgmode.org/elpa/") t)
(package-refresh-contents)

(package-install 'org)
(package-install 'org-plus-contrib)

(require 'org)
(require 'ox-extra)

(ox-extras-activate '(ignore-headlines))
```

Comment: Note that the OrgMode ELPA is now obsolete.